# Open fragment from activity button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So first of all I will explain how my app works.
First I start a `MainActivity`, and here I have two fragments, posted in a menu. These fragments work.

[image: Fragments]

Then I go to the `groups` fragment, and from this I open a new activity called `InfoAboutUsers`, and In this activity you get the option to view a `map`, and this map is made in a fragment.

What I'm trying to do here is to open a fragment, when I click on my button, inside this activity. Here I tried this:

**Function from activity**

```java
locationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        inflateUserListFragment();
    }
});


....

private void inflateUserListFragment(){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.user_location), mUserLocation);
    map fragment = new map();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

But when I do this the app crashes, and the activity doesn't start?

Comment: can you share your logs with errors? what kind of error do you have and from what line?

Comment: Is your `map` a fragment too? how do you set arguments to the `map` object?

Comment: Found the issue... Wrong `ID` to frameLayout